Espresso on Shabbos... ☕ Will this method work?
I've come across some fully-manual espresso machines, such as Flair 58x*. Assuming one holds like Rav Moshe Feinstein where there is no bishul in a kli shlishi, and one prepared his pre-ground coffee before Shabbos, would it be permissible to use one of these machines on Shabbos with kli-shlishi water? Could an elevated pressurized environment be considered as heating up the water in the chamber, or perhaps there are other problematic considerations?

*Please note that the "X model" is the one without any electronic components. Also please note this question is very different from the ones on this site, I searched. Asking uniquely about this machine.

“Also please note this question is very different from the ones on this site, I searched. Asking uniquely about this machine.“ In what way is this machine different than other manual espresso machines?

Nice username bro
